# Do you support SmsGatewayCenter SMS API Module?

Tags: sms

I am a customer of https://www.smsgatewaycenter.com/ from past 1 year and definitely like their service and would want to stick to them.

I have seen one of your plugin for sms with different provider, can I replicate this to smsgatewaycenter.com API? 
https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.sms.mysmsmantra

or do you have it ready with you? Please update. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM is open source software, so there's no "you" to address this to.  Anyone is free to make a plugin to interface CiviCRM with this provider.

As of right now, no one has - but SMS provider plugins are relatively simple, and if you (or someone you sponsored) was able to put in a few hours, you could likely make this happen!